# thumbnail over the youtubeVideoplayer in xml of android studio?

Tags: android, youtube-api, android-studio-2.3

How to put thumbnail over the youtubeVideoplayer in Layout-xml file of android studio 2.3.2, As I am able to play the youtube video in my app but I want to show the thumbnail of that video before playing video so that it look nice.

Answer (score 0):

you need to get the video's thumbnail seperately

You can get a thumbnail of your YouTube video using [this link](http://img.youtube.com/vi/VIDEO_ID/default.jpg) by replacing VIDEO_ID with your own video's ID.

Show this thumbnail before user plays the video

Answer (score 0):

Every you tube video have unique ID and that is the only difference in each you tube video URL. Like video, every thumbnail alo have unique ID which is of course the same as video which belongs. Basically you have to extract or put unique ID and then download thumbnail using your own methods for downloading bitmaps or using some third party library like `Glide`. Something like this:

```
String  url = MessageFormat.format("http://img.youtube.com/vi/{0}/hqdefault.jpg", idOfYourVideo);
Glide.with(YourActivityName.this).load(url).asBitmap().into(new 
     SimpleTarget<Bitmap>() {
        @Override
        public void onResourceReady(Bitmap resource, GlideAnimation<? super 
        Bitmap> glideAnimation) {
            thumbnail.setImageBitmap(resource);
        }
    });
```